# Open the most recent PDF in a folder

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to open the most recent file in a folder. In this folder, we have a lot of versions of different files, separated by date and time in the file name.

I can't figure out how to separate by the hour of modification.

The format is like this "Raio X - Grafico - 17.09.2018 07.39.pdf". The only thing that changes is the date and the hour, in the end of the name of the file, every new version.

```
 Dim FileSys, objFile, myFolder, c As Object
 Dim Fldname As String
 Dim FPath As String
 Dim FileN As String
 Dim MDataFile As String
 Dim Date1 As Date
 Dim RDate As String
 Dim Hour1 As Date
 Dim RHour As String

 Date1 = Now()
 RDate = Format(Date1, "dd.mm.yyyy")
 Hour1 = Time
 RHour = Format(Hour1, " hh.mm")
 FPath = "R:\TL - Comando de Montagem - Relatorios Internos\Raio X"
 FileN = FPath & "\" & "Raio X - Grafico - " & RDate & RHour & ".pdf"
 ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink _
 Address:=FileN, _
 NewWindow:=True, AddHistory:=True

 End Sub
```

I need to compare the System Hour with the hour of the files in the folder.

Comment: It looks to me like you're getting the current system time and creating a file name from that. This doesn't line up well with your question about opening an existing file...

Answer (score 0):

Since the positions are at a fixed distance from the end, you can use the Mid and Len functions.
Here's an example:

```
FileName = "Raio X - Grafico - 17.09.2018 07.39.pdf"
FileHour = Mid(FileName, Len(FileName) - 8, 2)
FileMinute = Mid(FileName, Len(FileName) - 5, 2)
```